# SilverStripe add to DataList child DataList

Tags: loops, datalist, silverstripe

I am trying to create a DataList with child DataList for a loop within a loop in a template:

```php
public function getAllCategoriesAndEntrys(){
    $categories = FitoCategory::get();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category->entries = $this->Items($category->ID);
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

My template looks like this:

```php
<% loop getAllCategoriesAndEntrys() %>
    $ID $Title <br>
    <% loop entries %>
        ------ $Title <br>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

In my example, I'm sure that:

`FitoCategory::get()` - returns all my 'FitoCategory' in object type `DataList`;

`$this->Items($category->ID)` - returns `DataList` with all child entries for FitoCategory by id;

I need a binding code instead:

```php
$category->entries = $this->Items($category->ID);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the query run isn't cached so new `FitoCategory` objects are created every time you loop over the list. This means any additional properties get lost.

Instead, you want to add the objects to an `ArrayList` and return that instead.

```php
public function getAllCategoriesAndEntrys(){
    $categories = FitoCategory::get();
    $list = ArrayList::create();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category->entries = $this->Items($category->ID);
        $list->push($category);
    }

    return $list;
}
```